# Notation regarding subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

In a paper about operator theory I'm currently studying I found the notation $M^{-}$ where $M$ is a closed, linear subspace of a seperable Hilbertspace $H$. Furthermore it's reducing for some bounded linear operator $T$ on $H$. What could this mean?

Comment: Might be helpful to say what paper it is

Comment: right, it's called m-isometric transformations of hilbert space vol i, by jim agler and mark stankus

Comment: On a quick skim of the paper the notation seems to be used to indicate closure. Where do you see it used on a closed subspace?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the author is assuming every subspace to be closed, since many things would not work out at all if you were not assuming it. e.g. existence of orthogonal projections on subspaces, existence of adjoints of restrictions and so forth